# Unable to parse folder using Bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a bash script that will execute 1 Linux command (`exiftool`) for each file in a certain folder in a for loop.

Example of how to run this comand: `exiftool /Users/user1/Documents/recovered/recup_dir.4/file_1.jpeg`

Here is what I managed to do:

```
for i in /Users/user1/Documents/recovered/recup_dir.4
  do
    exiftool i
done
```

The error I got is:

```
File not found: i.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `exiftool "$i"`, and you're not iterating files in a directory. Read a tutorial or something.

Comment: @Biffen I just need to have all the paths of all the files from the certain folder and to write this command (exiftool) before nothing to deal with tutorials of this command.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say, but the ‘script’ in your question is all made up. I suggest you read a Bash scripting tutorial to learn the basics, rather than expecting Bash to magically do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could likely use the `find` command to do this:

```
find /path/ -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec exiftool {} \;
```

> ↳ http://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for i in /Users/user1/Documents/recovered/recup_dir.4/*
do
  exiftool "$i"
done
```